# Where is the JSON credentials file for Ansible provision of Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine, ansible, ansible-2.x

I follow this guide http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/gce_module.html

And it indicates that `credentials_file` in JSON format could be used instead of the deprecated `pem_file`. Where can I get this credentials file?

Comment: Try to generate that file with this tutorial ---> https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#howtheywork

Comment: Thank you @Raul. I have got the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Developers Console Credentials page.
From the project drop-down, select your project.
On the Credentials page, select the Create credentials drop-down, then select Service account key.
From the Service account drop-down, select an existing serivce account or create a new one.
For Key type, select the JSON key option, then select Create. The file automatically downloads to your computer.
Put the *.json file you just downloaded in a directory of your choosing. This directory must be private (you can't let anyone get access to this), but accessible to your web server code.

Set the environment variable to the path of the JSON file downloaded.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#howtheywork